# возврат строки в MySQL запроск

Tags: mysql

[image: Нужно вернуть строку "Петров Сидоров 500 руб.]

Всем привет! Подскажите как можно это сделать? Нужно вернуть строчку "Петров Сидоров 500 руб." чтоб при запросе выбивало. Какая команда или строка нужна? Еще новичок и пытаюсь изучить эту базу данных, но пока не очень успешно

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT отправитель.фамилия, получатель.фамилия, результ_таблица.сумма
FROM таблица2 AS результ_таблица
JOIN таблица1 AS отправитель ON отправитель.ID = результ_таблица.ID_отправителя
JOIN таблица1 AS получатель ON получатель.ID = результ_таблица.ID_получателя
```

Почитай про JOIN'ы. И не делай такие вопросы, указывай реальные названия столбцов. Ибо в ответе получишь то, что написал в вопросе. Логику решения написал.

Еще лучше было бы, если бы ты через консоль приконнектился к mysql и скинул бы таблицу в нормальном виде, а не на картинке